# Proof of Chebychev inequality - help with integrals and a chain of (in)equalities

Tags: probability, integration, inequality, self-learning

I need help in deriving the following chain of (in)equalities as a part of proof of Chebychev inequality (from [these lecture notes](http://www.stat.washington.edu/thompson/S341_10/Notes/week3.pdf), 7.3):
$$\begin{align}
&\ge\int_{-\infty}^{\theta-a}(w-\theta)^2f_w(w)dw+\int_{\theta+a}^{+\infty}(w-\theta)^2f_w(w)dw\\
&\ge a^2\int_{-\infty}^{\theta-a}f_w(w)dw+a^2\int_{\theta+a}^{+\infty}f_w(w)dw=a^2P(|W-\theta|>a)
\end{align}$$

Comment: What exactly are you asking here? Which part, and what do you need to show?

Comment: @Clement C. In first part there is term $(w-a)^2$ under the integral; in second part there is the term $a^2$ outside the integral. What are the necessary steps in between to arrive from the first to second part? In addition, whay, at the end, the term $W-\theta$ has been written as modulus?

Comment: Just to be sure: the bounds on the integral are $\theta-a$ in both bounds? I would suspect a $\theta+a$ in one of the two...

Comment: @Clement C. You are correct. I have edited my question.

Comment: Seems a bit better. Where is it coming from, though (can you provide the source, or more context)? (For instance, is $\theta$ the expectation, etc.)

Comment: @Clement C. http://www.stat.washington.edu/thompson/S341_10/Notes/week3.pdf , part 7.3

Comment: Thanks. In particular, one of the equalities is an *inequality*. And it's $(w-\theta)^2$, not $(w-a)^2$.

Comment: @Clement C. Edited, thanks.

Comment: I took the liberty to edit your question to add the reference to the lecture notes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*I assume $f_w$ is the density of a probability distribution over $\mathbb{R}$, and $a > 0$. (Also, the integrals are well-defined, i.e. $X$ is a random variable with density $f_w$ which is square integrable.)*

- The second equality is the simplest: starting with the RHS,
  $$\begin{align}
  \mathbb{P}\{\lvert X-\theta\rvert > a\} 
  &=
  \mathbb{P}\{X-\theta > a\} + \mathbb{P}\{\theta - X > a\}\\
  &= \mathbb{P}\{X > \theta+a\} + \mathbb{P}\{ X < \theta -a\}\\
  &= \int_{\theta+a}^\infty f_w(w)dw + \int_{\infty}^{\theta -a}  f_w(w)dw.
  \end{align}$$
- For the first *in*equality: note that (i) when $w \leq \theta-a$, then $\theta-w \geq a > 0$ and  $(\theta-w)^2 \geq a^2$; and (ii) when $w \geq \theta+a$, then $w-\theta \geq a$ and  $(w-\theta)^2 \geq a^2$ as well. This gives that
  $$\begin{align}
  \int_{-\infty}^{\theta-a}(w-\theta)^2f_w(w)dw&+\int_{\theta+a}^{+\infty}(w-\theta)^2f_w(w)dw\\
  &\geq \int_{-\infty}^{\theta-a} a^2 f_w(w)dw+ \int_{\theta+a}^{+\infty} a^2 f_w(w)dw \\
  &=a^2 \int_{-\infty}^{\theta-a}f_w(w)dw+a^2 \int_{\theta+a}^{+\infty}f_w(w)dw
  \end{align}$$
  as wanted, since $f_w\geq 0$ (it's a density function).

Comment: If I understood correctly, when you say that (ii) inequality is the same as (i) - you mean $(a-b)^2=(b-a)^2$? Additionally, a silly question - why can we substitute $(w-\theta)^2$ with $a^2$ when $(w-\theta)^2$ is 'greater or equal' to $a^2$?

Comment: For the first point, yes. For the second: because we are looking for an inequality only, not an equality. If $f \geq g$ pointwise, then $\int f \geq \int g $.

Comment: Could you please elaborate a little bit more on the second point. Not sure I am following you.

Comment: So, focusing on the first integral (the second is the same): for every $w\leq \theta-a$, we have $$\underbrace{(w-\theta)^2 f_w(w)}_{"f(w)"} \geq \underbrace{a^2 f_w(w)}_{"g(w)"}.$$ This implies that $\int_{-\infty}^{\theta-a} f(w)dw \geq \int_{-\infty}^{\theta-a} g(w)dw$, that is $\int_{-\infty}^{\theta-a} (w-\theta)^2 f_w(w) dw \geq \int_{-\infty}^{\theta-a} a^2 f_w(w) dw$.

Comment: And when you say "we are looking for inequality only, not an equality"?

Comment: Because the above is fine because we are only looking for an inequality. The above "substitution" would be false in general, if you wanted an equality $=$ instead of the $\geq$ sign.

Comment: @Navi Did that clear your confusion?

Comment: I am still thinking about it.  I understand that this is because we are interested in values greater than $a$. However, I feel like there is still a missing part of the puzzle in my head.

Comment: To break it down: which part confuses you? Using letters instead of the integrals for simplicity of notation: we want to show $A + B \geq A'+B'$. To do so, we use the fact that $A\geq A'$ and $B\geq B'$. Is your issue in the first part (that "$A + B \geq A'+B'$" is implied by "$A\geq A'$ and $B\geq B'$") or the second (that we actually have $A\geq A'$ and $B\geq B'$)?

Comment: I am confused with the introduction of $a^2$. Is there any plain example of inequalities where we can use similar substitution in solving equation?

Comment: I don't follow you. We know that $(w-\theta)^2 \geq a^2$ (this was proven before) for every $w$ considered in the integral, *so* we use that inequality. See it as "reverse-engineering" if you want: it is a step that we proved is correct, and one that makes sense given what we want to establish in the end.

Comment: If we know $(A-B)^2\geq C^2$, then we can use $(A-B)^2=C^2$ to find values only greater than $C^2$? Is this true only in this case where we have the same inequalities from both sides?

Comment: Again, I don't see what you mean here. You are asking *how* the original person writing the proof figured out what to look for as inequality to try and prove?

Comment: Put differently: is your issue with the derivation above, or with *how* the original prover figured out these were the steps to follow?

Comment: @Navi Er. I can't really parse what you wrote, the comment doesn't display properly. If you want, we can chat in the Math.SE chat to clarify?

Comment: I would certainly like to clarify this, however I cannot go on chat at the moment. Alternatively, we can discuss this over email if it's OK with your or another time on chat?

Comment: Another time, then.

Comment: I will then contact you here through comment. Thank you very much for your time so far and patience. I really appreciate it.